# How to clear the console in C without flickering

Tags: c, console, console-application

I am creating a program that updates in real time the data placed in a histogram drawn on the console. But when i use `system("cls")` - i am using Windows - I see the flicker of the function `system("cls")`. I tried with the `<regex.h>` module and print the expression `"\e[1;1H\e[2J"` but it doesn't work. The histogram I'm trying to figure is like the following

[image: Histogram image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the histogram you are trying to represent?

Assuming that you print each histogram "version" in a loop you could add the carriage return char (`\r`) at the end of your output so that, on the next iteration, you'd start printing on the same line in the console and overwrite your previous histogram.

Comment: Showing the code might also help. It is not clear, how `regex.h` is related to your task.